# What are the opensource alternatives for MS Project in order to manage Project management?

Tags: software-recommendation, alternative, project-management

Can anybody suggest some  project management open source alternative software for MS PROJECT?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[**GanttProject Open Source**](http://www.ganttproject.biz/) by Dmitry Barashev, Alexandre Thomas | Mac, Windows, Linux

GanttProject is a cross-platform desktop tool for project scheduling and management. It runs on Windows, Linux and MacOSX, it is free and its code is opensource.

[**ProjectLibre Open Source**](http://www.projectlibre.com/product/projectlibre-open-source) | Mac, Windows, Linux

ProjectLibre is a Java-based project management solution that gives Microsoft Project a run for its money. Offering a UI similar enough to ease the transition from Microsoft's market leader.

[**GNOME Planner Open Source**](http://live.gnome.org/Planner/) by Richard Hult and Mikael Hallendal, | Windows, Linux

Planner is the GNOME project management tool. Its goal is to be an easy-to-use no-nonsense cross-platform project management application.

[**Calligra Plan Open Source**](http://www.calligra.org/plan/) by Calligra Suite | Linux

Calligra Plan (formerly KPlato) is a project management application. It is intended for managing moderately large projects with multiple resources.

[**2-Plan Free**](http://2-plan.com/) | Mac, Windows, Linux

2-plan Project Management Systems offers three PM tools: a free desktop system, an open-source software for multiple projects and teams, and a scrum board.

Source: 
http://alternativeto.net/

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [RationalPlan Single](http://www.rationalplan.com/single-project-management-software.php). It is not open source but it is free for Linux users.

Answer (score 0):

RationalPlan is good and the single version is free on Linux. Gantter also hasn't been mentioned here and is fully integrated with Google Drive. If you scroll down this article, there are some good open source alternatives which work on both Linux and Mac: 
[Source: https://machow2.com/best-alternatives-microsoft-project-mac/](https://machow2.com/best-alternatives-microsoft-project-mac/)

Comment: Gantter not opening an mmp file in my case...